# D IDE with auto-format

Tags: ide, d, autoformatting

I just started learning D.  Does anyone know of a good IDE for D that has auto-format capabilities?  DDT for eclipse doesn't seem to have anything besides syntax highlighting.

Comment: By auto-formatting, do you mean something that will convert existing source code to your preferred format?  If so, I imagine C++ tools would work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, at the moment, there is no competition for the MonoDevelop + Mono-D plugin. Link: http://mono-d.alexanderbothe.com/ . I used Code::Blocks for years, but now I use MonoDevelop exclusively.

If you prefer Eclipse - try the Eclipse DDT project: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/ddt/

If you prefer Windows-only IDE, then perhaps Visual D is the best choice - http://www.dsource.org/projects/visuald .

Comment: Thanks, I will.  I'm somewhat hesitant to try anything that doesn't integrate with eclipse because I'm used to all of eclipse's refactoring tools, but this doesn't look too different

Comment: That doesn't have auto-format.  It's the reason I posted this in the first place.  It also doesn't seem to underline compile errors.  And it doesn't work with gdmd or gdc.  Plus the syntax highlighting is minimal and auto-complete doesn't suggest anything from the libraries, only from code in the project.  And there's no auto-including

Comment: I have been going in circles trying to install MonoDevelop.  First I tried the one in the main repository, but it doesn't have support for D.

Then I tried adding mono-d.alexanderbothe.com as a source, but that requires MonoDevelop 2.95, and this is only version 2.6

Then I tried downloading the source and compiling it, but the configure file said there was a file missing.

I finally gave up.  There doesn't seem to be any way to get an older version of the Mono-D plugin or a newer version of MonoDevelop

Comment: In my case I use the stable MonoDevelop RPM from Fedora's repository. Mono-D is in the central plugin-database, so after installing MonoDevelop, all I had to do is to tell it to download and install Mono-D... Similar path is for Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Code::Blocks.

http://www.codeblocks.org/

It's cross platform and provides good (if not perfect) D integration. It can easily be configured to compile with DMD, GDC, or LDC.